# Applying css class according to value in Select2 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 select in which I want to change the background color according to the value.

However, the option which would have allowed me to do it (`formatSelectionCssClass`) seem to have been removed from the V4.0 of select2

I have tried using the `templateResult` with the folowing :

```
templateResult: function (item) {
            if (item.loading)
                return item.text;

            var element = $("#" + item._resultId);

            switch (item.text) {
                case "0":
                    element.addClass("element-0");
                    break;
                case "1":
                    element.addClass("element-1");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    element.addClass("element-2");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    element.addClass("element-3");
                    break;
            }

            return item.text;
        },
```

Edit : JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ubswjv95/

Comment: jsFiddle would be usefull!

Comment: Added fiddle, see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find element by your selector because in moment when you trying to get  `var element = $("#" + item._resultId);` items aren't added in dropdown. I have made update of your fiddle where I instead of returning just text of item returns `div` with your classes, and seems fine https://jsfiddle.net/ubswjv95/2/. This solution need little tuneup but this is the way you should go.

Comment: I had wrote that in my question but I should have failed somewhere as it's no longer there ... Anyway, your solution kinda work but as each li have a padding, any enclosed div can't have the full parent width and height, leading to this ugly small color box, which is a deal breaker. I would realy like to have a way to just access the li element.

Comment: You can handle that in css, i haven't fide better solution https://jsfiddle.net/ubswjv95/4/

Comment: I'm not fond of this solution which require to override something already overridden in my select2 bootstrap theme, which would put a dent in maintenability if the theme change or something ... But I guess web dev is always about compromises ... If no one gives a better answer by the end of the day, I will mark yours as accepted

Comment: Ok, if I found something better I'll let you know.